# Tedious alarm problem in Draw Event in GMS2

Tags: alarm, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

I am using `alarm[0]` in Draw Event.

When you set `alarm[0] = 1`, The code in alarm event will execute 70 times; But when you set `alarm[0] = 2`, The code in alarm event will execute 1 time, which is expected.

I cannot figure out why. The `game_speed` is 60.

Comment: The draw event is similair to the Step event, which will be repeately called every time. Possible chances are that the Alarm[0] already ran out of time before called again. Are you sure you need to place your alarm[0] in the Draw Event?

Comment: please provide the full code you have in draw and alarm[0]